# DataGridView & Linq

Tags: linq, datagridview

I am trying to use the following linq query on my datagridview:

```
var count = dgv_Checks.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                      .Count(row => row.Cells["SubmitToAch"]
                      .Value.ToString() == "True");
```

I allow adds to this datagridview so there is an 'add row' at the bottom.  Every time it reaches that add row, it gives me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", not only in this query but others.

Is there a way to handle linq queries or a datagridview and have it not look at this add row?

Also, how do I fix the query above to skip that row?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a null check?

```
var count = dgv_Checks.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Count(row => row.Cells["SubmitToAch"] != null && row.Cells["SubmitToAch"].Value.ToString() == "True");
```

Comment: That was my thought but I still get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when I hit that row.

Comment: Dang I just noticed I put Null reference exceptions as the error message on the original post. I fixed that... sry.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
row.Cells["SubmitToAch"].Value != null
```

Answer (score 0):

An older post but I feel compelled to answer since the same problem was bugging me earlier today. The solution proposed by the accepted answer (to check for null) still results in an object reference exception for me, but an IsNewRow check skipped the added row correctly:

```
var count = dgv_Checks.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Count(row => !row.IsNewRow && row.Cells["SubmitToAch"].Value.ToString() == "True");
```